# my post commit hook is not working due to Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits.how to solve it?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

my post comit hook is not working due to Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits.
And i had tired this below code

```
wget -q --auth-no-challenge --user USERNAME --password PASSWORD --output-document - \
'JENKINS_URL/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)'
```

but the error is

[image: https://content.screencast.com/users/suvekshakya123/folders/Jing/media/ef93a26c-3b2a-443d-b419-cdb82d4bafae/2017-07-17_1715.png]

Comment: Why are you using Post commit hook? Is it just to trigger build or any other steps?

Comment: I have use this post comit hook  to build the  solution instantly after the svn commit is made.